# How do Chrome Devtools 3rd Party Badges get added?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I noticed not all requests are accurately tagged with the new 3rd party badging in chrome devtools.

How are new ones submitted, and is the data publicly available anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3rd party badges, or "Product Registry" uses Chrome devtool's remote module system. It works by asking a remote server for the specific version of the product registry for your chrome hash.

Because of complicated reasons we had to hash the domain matching and compare against the hashes.

Here's the file that contains the data:
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/product_registry_impl/ProductRegistryData.js

Here's the consumer of the data:
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/product_registry_impl/ProductRegistryImpl.js

We do have a form to submit issues here:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSchz2FdcQ-rRllzl8BbhWaTRRY-12BpPjW6Hr9e1-BpCA083w/viewform

If you want to suggest adding items please file a bug at http://crbug.com/

This was the only public data we were able to get open sourced.